# How to display Jquery dialogbox on asp:Button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to JQuery and trying to display a Yes/No confirmation dialog box when the user clicks on an aspx button. When the dialog box gets displayed to the user he can click the Yes or No button and depending upon the user action i want to execute different code present in code behind file i.e. in aspx.cs

I have tried with the following code but not succeded in my objective.

Code present in aspx page:

```
<link href="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("#myButton").click(showDialog);

        //variable to reference window
        $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

        //instantiate the dialog
        $myWindow.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {

                },
                "No": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    );
    //function to show dialog   
    var showDialog = function() {
        //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
        $myWindow.show();
        //open the dialog
        $myWindow.dialog("open");
    }

    //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
    var closeDialog = function() {
        $myWindow.dialog("close");
    }

</script>

<form id="testconfirmJQ" name="testconfirmJQ" runat="server">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery UI Modal Submit</legend>
    <p><label for="email">E-mail:</label><br />
    <input id="emailJQ" type="text" name="emailJQ" value="" /></p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="myButton_Click" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="myDiv" title="Verify Form jQuery UI Style"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span> You entered your e-mail address as:</p><p id="dialog-email"></p><p>
    If this is correct, click Submit Form.</p><p>To edit, click Cancel.<p></div>
</form>
```

In code behind the event handler is empty for now. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem you are running into? Do you just need help with creating a specific post when the user clicks yes or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery is client side and you want to execute server side code in your .aspx.cs file, you could try saving a value indicating what the user responded to the prompt and they doing a postback so the server side can execute the appropriate code.

You might look into using the [Button.OnClientClick Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) which can execute client side code before the postback. Still use the jQuery dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the onclick attribute of asp:button.  There should be no need for it -- you are not doing server side actions.

You could also change it to an `<input>` of type button.